# Disable nav bar element based on url

Tags: jsp, thymeleaf

I took over a project. And there is a navbar to navigate to different sites.

This file with the navbar is includes in every file. So far it was no problem.

But now I will add a new element called "Holiday" . This should only be visible on a specific URL .

It should be visible for urls starting with /user/.. but not on the ones starting with /admin/.. .

Is there a way to do this ? This project is done with jsp by the way. It was done a couple of years ago. But I would also be interested if it possible in Thymeleaf.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand fa fa-home fa-2x" style="color: darkblue; font-size: 20px" href="<c:url value="/user/workingtimeNow"/>">Home</a>
            <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_MANAGER')">
            <a class="navbar-brand fa fa-cog fa-2x" style="color: darkblue; font-size: 20px" href="<c:url value="/manager/home"/>">Admin</a>
            </sec:authorize>
            <a class="navbar-brand fa " style="color: darkblue; font-size: 20px" href="<c:url value="/user/workingtimeNow"/>">Holiday</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the URI (the part after hostname in requested  URL) with this method:

String uri = request.getRequestURI()

And after, makes if/then testing based on this ‘uri’ String contents (contains “/admin/“ or not for example) ...

Kind regards,

Comment: ok. Thanks. Indeed this would be one possiblity. But I already decided to not use this navbar which is included everywhere, instead place the button somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Alicia. If my response is correct for your original question, could you validate it because I’m starting on Stackoverflow and need reputations points to progress. Thanks